# Storing Data from GridView in WinRT

Tags: gridview, windows-runtime

I have created a GridView layout that starts out empty. Users then enter data that and a GridViewItem is created for each entry. The data is bound to a collection in the code-behind.

What is the best way to save this collection so that it persists when the app is closed and reopened?

I am currently using SQLite but I was hoping there was something easier that would allow me to store the actual objects instead of having to convert them into strings for the database.

Comment: I ran into problems using the suggested helper class with an ObservableCollection of items. I ended up finding and using the TCD.Serialization package from NuGet. It seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how much data it is you want to save and how you want to use it. 
If it's not thousands of objects,  saving it locally inside the app will be enough for you. 
There is a great helper class on CodePlex that allows this, you can find it here: [Link to codeplex](http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/).

The helper class is generic, so you can save and load all kinds of objects very easily without the effort of creating a database. It's using async and it supports storage and load of data using the [RoamingFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder), [TemporaryFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder) & [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) storage folders